# Angular Error when Accesing Length of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
$scope.educations = [];
console.log($scope.educations.length); //works!,shows 0. 
$scope.addEducation = function () {
   if ($scope.educations.length < 3) { // Error
   ...
   }
```

addEducation(): it adds a form to the UI, and the only place i am using educations array again in the removeEducations() which removes the form from the UI.

when i call addEducation function And the error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Why is this happening..Please help
(btw this was working fine yesterday)

Comment: Is `educations` changed somewhere in between

Comment: `educations` is being set as undefined at some point in the code.

Comment: could be that you are calling addEducation from a different Controller. Please provide more code

Comment: but when i log , i can see 0 first then i see the error, means the educations is initialized right?

Comment: @artdias90 everything is in one controller itself

Comment: Provide more code details

Comment: Guys thanks, it seems i was manipulating the array somewhere else too, i was assigning data from db without check for null. and the array was nullified.

sorry for asking. and thanks a lot guys.